# VBA code to access the third cell in a row in a Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to this and I'm trying to merge some cells and apply some formatting based on whether the third cell of a row is empty.  So far I have:

```
For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
    For Each rRow In tTable.Rows
        If Len ('third cell in row' < 3) Then
            <do stuff> 
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I have no idea how to access/specify the third cell in the row though? I've looked at a lot of examples but don't seem to be able to get it quite right.

Comment: So I figured out how to do this (r.Cells(3).Range.Text < 3) but now I'm stuck on how to merge the this cell and the three cells next to it.  I've found some examples of merging using a range:

Dim mrgrng As Range
With Selection.Tables(1)
    For i = 1 To 2
        Set mrgrng = .Cell(i, 1).Range
        mrgrng.End = .Cell(i, 2).Range.End
        mrgrng.Cells.Merge
    Next i
End With

But I'm getting confused when I try and apply it to my case.  What does the . in front of the Cell signify?  I'm assuming I use 'r.Index' to access the number of the row inside my loop.

Comment: You should improve your question, by using "edit" option below the tags.